# FULL OUTER JOIN is not returning content of all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have 3 tables as mentioned below.

**TABLES**

*BUG*

```
Id | Name | Other information ...
1  | Bug1 | ...
2  | Bug2 | ...
3  | Bug3 | ...
4  | Bug4 | ...
5  | Bug5 | ...
```

*LINK*

```
Id  | Test_id | Bug_id
100 | 1000    | 4
101 | 1100    | 2
102 | 1200    | 2
103 | 1200    | 5
```

*TEST*

```
Id   | Name | Other information ...
1000 | TC1  | ...
1100 | TC2  | ...
1200 | TC3  | ...
1300 | TC4  | ...
1400 | TC5  | ...
1500 | TC6  | ...
```

**REQUEST**

```
SELECT Bug.Id, Bug.Name, Test.Id, Test.Name
FROM Test FULL OUTER JOIN Link ON Link.Test_id = Test.Id
FULL OUTER JOIN Bug ON Link.Bug_id = Bug.Id
INNER JOIN Test_Detail ON Test_Detail.Test_id = Test.Id
INNER JOIN Release ON Release.Id = Test.Release_id
INNER JOIN Cycle ON Cycle.Release_id = Release.Id
```

However, this is not providing the expected result ...

**EXPECTED RESULT**

- if there is a link, I would like to get information about the bug and
  the test
- if there is a bug without link, I would like to get
  information about the bug
- if there is a test without link, I would like to get information about the test

*Result*

```
BugId | BugName | TestId | TestName
1     | Bug1    |
2     | Bug2    | 1100   | TC2
2     | Bug2    | 1200   | TC3
3     | Bug3    |
4     | Bug4    | 1000   | TC1
5     | Bug5    | 1200   | TC2
      |         | 1300   | TC4
      |         | 1400   | TC5
      |         | 1500   | TC6
```

**CONCLUSION**

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is not the correct join to use ? Can you please help to understand why it is not working as expected?

Thank you

**EDIT 1**

Result based on Charlieface answer.

I'm getting the bug, the test and the link. But I need only the link if it exists. If there is no link, I need the test and the bug detail. As mentioned on Expected Result section above.

```
BugId | BugName | TestId | TestName
      |         | 1100   | TC2
      |         | 1200   | TC3
2     | Bug2    |        | 
2     | Bug2    | 1100   | TC2
2     | Bug2    | 1200   | TC3
```

**EDIT 2**

*Full request*

(`TESTCYCL` is `TEST` in this post)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
B.BG_BUG_ID
, B.BG_STATUS
, B.BG_SUMMARY
, B.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_13
, B.BG_SEVERITY
, B.BG_PRIORITY
, B.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_10
, B.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_08
, R.REL_NAME
, RC2.RCYC_NAME
, B.BG_DETECTION_DATE
, B.BG_RESPONSIBLE
, B.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_03
, B.BG_USER_03
, B.BG_CLOSING_DATE
, B.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_19
, B.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_18
, B.BG_DETECTED_BY
, TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID
, TC.TC_TEST_ID
, T.TS_NAME
, TC.TC_STATUS
, T.TS_USER_TEMPLATE_05
, CF.CF_ITEM_NAME
, C.CY_CYCLE
, RC1.RCYC_NAME
, TC.TC_USER_TEMPLATE_06
, TC.TC_USER_TEMPLATE_05
, TC.TC_USER_TEMPLATE_08
FROM TESTCYCL AS TC
INNER JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES AS RC1 ON TC.TC_ASSIGN_RCYC = RC1.RCYC_ID
INNER JOIN TEST AS T ON TC.TC_TEST_ID = T.TS_TEST_ID
INNER JOIN CYCLE AS C ON TC.TC_CYCLE_ID = C.CY_CYCLE_ID
INNER JOIN CYCL_FOLD AS CF ON C.CY_FOLDER_ID = CF.CF_ITEM_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN LINK AS L ON L.LN_ENTITY_ID = TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN BUG AS B
INNER JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES AS RC2 ON B.BG_DETECTED_IN_RCYC = RC2.RCYC_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASES AS R ON B.BG_DETECTED_IN_REL = R.REL_ID
ON L.LN_BUG_ID = B.BG_BUG_ID
```

Comment: What is the inner join, that is likely affecting it. @DaleK Huh, since when does `full join` do that?

Comment: I have 4 inner join to get content from other tables but only linked to `test` or `bug`. It should not affect the linkage between `test`, `bug` and `link`.

Comment: That's what *you* think. Please [edit] and add the full query

Comment: I added `INNER JOIN` in the request. It is only used to get more information about the test.

Comment: FULL JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a FULL JOIN ON, a WHERE, HAVING or INNER JOIN requiring some column(s) of the right/left/2 [sic] table(s) to be not NULL removes rows NULL-extended for columns of such table(s), ie leaves only RIGHT/LEFT/INNER [sic] JOIN ON rows, ie "turns FULL JOIN into RIGHT/LEFT/INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: In code questions give a [mre]--minmal code that is working code extended by minimal code to not work. Say what you expected instead & why, justified by referencing authoritative documenation. (Debugging basic.) This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. [ask] PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy thank you for your comment. I added more info about the edit.

Comment: Hi. This still doesn't say what that value is supposed to be. This still has a needless line saying "EDIT". PS This still doesn't have code that can be cut & pasted & run. (But--This is still a duplicate of very old questions. You can click to say so if you agree that it is.)

Comment: In the section Expected Result, then Result of the post, there is a table with detail of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify via edit, not comments. Also that ">" isn't clear. Use enough words to say what you mean. Seems maybe you are trying to say that it's the desired output for the input given earlier, but you're not saying that. If so, shouldn't it always have been in your post, up near the corresponding input? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: I will for my next post take into account your comments, thank you. To summarize, my goal is to get the result of the table in the section Expected Result, then Result. This Edit section is just used to show the result of Charlieface answer which is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: That "full request" might be relevant to you but it is irrelevant to the post/question. PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. Owners & followers of posts always get notified.

Comment: It has been requested on a comment so I posted it ...

Comment: What comment do you think requested it? It is not needed for a [mre]. What is needed for that is executable table initialization code to run with the 1st query, instead of the grids you give. Ideally, formatted with justified columns. But as I also said your query should have stopped at the first subexpression with unexpected result. But please don't change that query now, it will invalidate the answer posts. You are not acting on many useful things I've said.

Comment: The comment of Charlieface in his anwser.

Comment: I can't see why you think that, and regardless, the 2nd query doesn't belong.  PS The final ON would be much more clear if put after 'BUG'. Do you understand that putting it last means the 2 final inner joins are done before the final outer join? Look at how it parses.

Comment: Yes of course, if I put the ON before the 2 final inner joins I'm not getting all test without bug associated.

Comment: Give a [mre] & then write your code the way an answer that runs using it is written. Your problem is, not composing a [mre]. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to reorder your joins.**

Put all `inner join`s relating to one table together with that table.:

```sql
SELECT Bug.Id, Bug.Name, Test.Id, Test.Name
FROM Test
INNER JOIN Test_Detail ON Test_Detail.Test_id = Test.Id
INNER JOIN Release ON Release.Id = Test.Release_id
INNER JOIN Cycle ON Cycle.Release_id = Release.Id
FULL OUTER JOIN Link ON Link.Test_id = Test.Id
FULL OUTER JOIN Bug ON Link.Bug_id = Bug.Id
```

Let us assume you want to join something onto `Bug` also. For this, you need to nest the `ON` conditions:

```sql
SELECT Bug.Id, Bug.Name, Test.Id, Test.Name
FROM Test
INNER JOIN Test_Detail ON Test_Detail.Test_id = Test.Id
INNER JOIN Release ON Release.Id = Test.Release_id
INNER JOIN Cycle ON Cycle.Release_id = Release.Id
FULL OUTER JOIN Link ON Link.Test_id = Test.Id
FULL OUTER JOIN Bug
      INNER JOIN Bug_Detail bd ON bd.Bug_id = Bug.id
  ON Link.Bug_id = Bug.Id
```

Note that, contrary to popular opinion, parenthesis `()` do not make a difference here, although they are useful visually. It's the order of the `ON` clauses that matter: `Bug_detail` inner join is nested inside the full join of `Bug`

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting answer ! However, if there is a link, request returns one row for the bug, one row for the bug and the test linked and one row for the test. I put an example in the post. If there is a link, I dont have to get the bug and test record.

Comment: There was a mistype that I had copied from your original edit, now fixed. Are you using **any other** `join` or `where` predicates, as this should work?

Comment: I'm not using where clause, and for the joins you explained how to do for Test and Bug. However it is strange, for some bug, I have a row with bug details and another row with bug and test detail. Same bug but present 2 times (one time without associated test and one time with associated test)

Comment: That's not possible unless you either have other predicates or joins, or the `bugid` doesn't match (perhaps a trailing space or something). Judging by the result you've given, you **do** have an extra predicate *somewhere* (perhaps elsewhere in the query). Please [edit] and add your current query **in full**

Comment: I added the full query. I don't see any difference with your answer (expect the SELECT of course)

Comment: OK probably `RELEASE_CYCLES` or `RELEASES` is doubling up the rows. I would advise to add table aliases, such as `TEST AS t` and then refer to them in the select such as `t.TS_NAME`, then it is easier to see what's what

Comment: I put alias on all table but nothing changed. Very strange ...

Comment: By putting `FROM Test FULL OUTER JOIN Link ON Link.Test_id = Test.Id INNER ...`  instead of `FROM Test INNER ... FULL OUTER JOIN Link ON Link.Test_id = Test.Id` it seems to be better ...

Answer (score 1):

Your inner joins are turning the full outer join into something else.  Rearrange the joins and use parentheses:

```
SELECT Bug.Id, Bug.Name, Test.Id, Test.Name
FROM (Test JOIN
      Test_Detail
      ON Test_Detail.Test_id = Test.Id JOIN
      Release
      ON Release.Id = Test.Release_id JOIN
      Cycle
      ON Cycle.Release_id = Release.Id
     ) FULL OUTER JOIN
     Link
     ON Link.Test_id = Test.Id FULL OUTER JOIN
     Bug
     ON Link.Bug_id = Bug.Id;
```

Comment: Parenthesis do nothing, it's the order of the `ON` clauses

Comment: @philipxy . . . Because that logic could be anywhere in the `FROM` clause.  If it follows other table references, the parentheses are needed (and that was the original way I wrote the query).  Thank you for asking.  It is also tricky to understand whether the `FULL JOIN` applies to *all* the inner joins before it or just to the most recent table.  The results are quite different, and I prefer the parentheses in these cases to be very clear on the intention.

Comment: I don't understand "that logic could be anywhere in the FROM clause". I suppose you mean what I have expected, that you used the parentheses to suggest that the enclosed table was best thought of as a unit in a clearest structuring of the query meaning, as one might instead use a CTE for and/or one might use to indicate what value a comment is describing. But it is very often true that we could do that but we don't.

Comment: Anyway I think the question post's specification is incoherent & the presentation as a whole is a mess.

Comment: I don't understand your "whether the FULL JOIN applies to all the inner joins" because a join always takes everything to its left as left argument. Although cross & inner join are commuative so we can rearrange the order of arguments in chains of them. (As long as columns in ONs stay in scope. But we have similar options for rearranging where ON conjuncts go.)